# 2017 iMac on Ventura stops booting at spaceman_scan_free_blocks - what to do?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, mac, macos-ventura

My Mac stops booting at spaceman_scan_free_blocks and then just hangs there indefinitely. I tried all the usual, repairing disk in recovery, etc but nothing works. Singleuser / safe mode not working too.

Anything I could do over command line? Mac is iMac 2017 running Ventura.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I checked all of those. However, most of those are four hackintoshes. Apparently it occurs as a drive issue on some systems but not on apple’s ones. I didn’t do anything special, I was just using the system. However, I did recently install bitdefender antivirus on the computer. Bout two weeks ago. Also, the number of hits for this particular search is very low. Less than 20 in total.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: What? Did you read my comment?!? I have an actual Mac.

Comment: I read your comment, hence the vote. Clarify in your actual question.

Comment: You've tried resetting the SMC and NVRAM/PRAM, right? Do you have the original Apple drive, or have you replaced it with an aftermarket part? Can you Safe Boot it? Searching for `ventura slow boot` also brings results referring to a recent system upgrade.

Comment: Tetsujin - For someone who is considering legalities, you sure don’t show high reading comprehension proficiency. 
@Peregrino69 I did not try resetting pram/vram, will try. I have to fix this today - what happens if I reinstall in place?

Comment: @mrmut no need to be insulting, I didn't comment on your spelling ability. vote retracted, but that attitude means you're on your own as far as I'm concerned. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I've no clue what reinstallation will do, never had to. I'd try with [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-ph/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac). Hope your Time Machine's up to date...

Comment: @Peregrino69 Iz might have something to do with the latest update. Seems plausible. I will try recommended stuff to fix it in half a hour when I get home.

Comment: If you can get it resolved (fingers crossed for the reset :-)) please do write an answer. If not, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778257/edit) the question for new info instead of commenting. I'm removing my previous ones just to leave space for Those In The Know.

Comment: I will compile everything, it is a bit hard on the phone. No working computer here. Anyways,  pram /Nvram/smc reset didn’t work. Any idea how to roll back the update install and prevent booting apps from command prompt on recovery? However, I think this is system corruption in Q. Maybe something like DISM on Mac?

Comment: Nothing helped. In the end I reinstalled the MacOS and the computer first rebooted a few times and then stuck in the same position as before. Tbh, I am not sure what now.

Comment: Ona call with apple. They require reinstall grom USB so I am preparing the stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was no saving the installation.

In the call with Apple, they told me that there are some corrupted files on the system that can not be repaired, and they advised fully formatting and reinstalling the system.

Apple diagnostics, NVRAM/PRAM and SMC reset and other usual stuff did not help. I did not find command line tools that could scan and fix the disk in the spirit of SFC and DISM commands on Windows.

I used external USB SSD with mac installation to access files, copied them to another drive (2x) and then bombed the system and reinstalled it.

It is a hassle, but unfortunately nothing else would have helped.

I have reinstalled the mac using USB stick with latest Ventura on it and all now seems dandy. In retrospect, Windows machines seem much more repairable than Mac when c*ap hits the fan, but it is what it is.

I presume that the issue I faced was due to relatively old system (about 5y) that had been upgraded several times. If I have stayed on Catalina I originally used for years, this probably wouldn't have happened, for a while at least.